# Facebook login page is mirrored when in RTL

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk, right-to-left

I've set my WP8 app to be RTL (right to left) and than used the Facebook c# SDK for WP8.

This is my relevant Facebook c# code:
`session = await FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync();`

Now the problem is that the Facebook log in page is all mirrored and unlike the WP8 mirror the texts are also mirrored so they are sort of "backwards".

Is it a bug or can I fix it?

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it :)

Before the line in the question I added this:

`App.RootFrame.FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;`

To return the app into LTR so the Facebook page will be formatted correctly and not mirrored.

In order to return it after the login had finished I added this line when I finished with the login:

`App.RootFrame.FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.RightToLeft;`

It happend because the facebook login page is shown inside a Browser control so the actual text doesn't get mirrored correctly.

I guess the Facebook C# SDK people should have thought of it.. so I think we can say it sort of a bug.

Hope I helped you, future viewers!